# Out of range index this.buf.utf8Slice

Tags: javascript, avro

I have a kafka stream with avro message using the confluent.io kafka package.  This is working fine for the java applications.  But I am now trying to read in these messages in javascript.

I've been attempting to use the kafka-node + avsc packages to decode the messages from a buffer array to string, using the schema.  I know that confluent puts the first 5 bytes as a magic byte (0) + 4 bytes for the schema Id.

So I slice the Buffer to remove those bytes and attempt to send this to avsc to decode.  But I get an error

> return this.buf.utf8Slice(pos, pos + len);
>
> RangeError: out of range index
>       at RangeError (native)
>       at Tap.readString (C:\git\workflowapps\workItemsApp\node_modules\avsc\lib\utils.js:452:19)
>       at StringType._read (C:\git\workflowapps\workItemsApp\node_modules\avsc\lib\types.js:612:58)

Also attempting to manually decode this leaves lots of non-utf8 characters and I am losing data that way.

Sample Code:

```
  consumer.on('message', function(message) {
      var val = message.value.slice(4);
      sails.log.info('val buffer', val, val.length);
      sails.log.info('hex',val.toString('hex'));
      var type = avro.parse({"type":"record",
       "name":"StatusEvent",
        "fields":[{"name":"ApplicationUUID","type":"string"},
        {"name":"StatusUUID","type":"string"},
        {"name":"Name","type":"string"},
        {"name":"ChangedBy","type":"string"},
        {"name":"ChangedByUUID","type":"string"},
        {"name":"ChangedAt","type":"long"}]
      });

      var decodedValue = type.fromBuffer(val);
      sails.log.info('Decoded', decodedValue);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `slice(4)` should be `slice(5)` (otherwise you're only skipping 4 out of the 5 header bytes). You might also be able to find helpful information [here](https://github.com/mtth/avsc/issues/22).

Comment: I thought slice started at zero.  Now it's a precision loss error, which I think is the long in the schema.  If I change that to string, the error changes to a truncated buffer...ugh.  I know there are no nulls in this data.

Comment: Switching longs and strings won't work. To fix the precision loss error, you should use a "big integer" library; here are the steps: https://github.com/mtth/avsc/wiki/Advanced-usage#custom-long-types

Comment: Basically this has shown me another issue, that I already knew about and had not fixed yet.  I have C# ticks coming in on the avro, which I really don't want.  Fix that first.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: I have the same problem and slicing 5 bytes didn't help. Confluent ksql-datagen produces really confusing data. Can somebody help? I was slicing once 6 bytes another time 17 bytes can't figure out algorithm how many bytes are irrelevant in payload.